# jquery bind event with ajax content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

We have an external js file loaded on our static html page with a jQueryUI dialog opening a url with `jQuery.load()` from a button click.  Inside the ajax content returned is a handful of `input` elements, all `number` type.  We need to bind the `keydown` and `change` events to the number inputs, however it's not binding since the `.bind()` is happening before the elements are in the DOM from the ajax result.  We know about `.on()` but having an awfully hard time wiring it up.  I know we're missing something simple; any suggestions?

Basic Fiddle recreation: http://jsfiddle.net/jbwebtech/wvufLket/

Comment: [Understanding Event Delegation.](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There's nothing too hard to grasp that it's not already explained pretty decently inside the jQuery [`.on()` documentation: http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)
http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/

```
$(staticElementParent).on("event1 event2", dynamicElement, function(){ /*stuff*/ });
```

In your specific case:

***[fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wvufLket/2/)***

```
var ajax_content = '<input type="number"><br><input type="number"><br><input type="number"><br><input type="number">';

$(function () {

    console.log('jquery ready');

    $("body").on('input', 'input[type=number]', function (event) { 
        console.log('on() input successful');
    });

    // "AJAX" ;)
    $('button').click(function(){
       $('#ajax_container').html(ajax_content);
    })

});
```

As always, read the Docs

Comment: thanks for the example; I was unable to get it working with the explanations in the jquery docs, hence my post.  Ciao.

Answer (score -1):

Can't you just put your bind the callback of the .load() function? Or if you can't(im not sure), you can change a variable in the callback and check if it's loaded in the bind.

Or you can put the bind in the file that loaded with jquery(at the end of it).

Sorry, i can't comment yet.